# iOS auto-layout and size class in portrait and landscape

Tags: ios

I design my layouts using auto-layout and size class. Now I have this layout in portrait
[image]

When click the change button, the blue view's frame and the red view's frame will exchange

```
    @IBAction func change(sender: AnyObject) {

    let frame = view1.frame
    view1.frame = view2.frame
    view2.frame = frame
}
```

now it looks like:

[image]

then I change iPhone's orientation to landscape, I hope the red view will stay in the top position, however, it changes to:
[image]

Could anybody help me to figure out how to implement this? Thanks for any help!
Here is the sample project:
https://github.com/SomnusLee1988/SamplePorject.git

Comment: Seems like it could be an auto layout issue... Are you updating the constraints when you swap the views? Will you post the relevant code?

Comment: @JeffLewis, Hi, I have upload the sample project to git

Comment: you need to change the constraint of layout as well it will help you

Comment: @harish, do you mean that I need change the layout to set red view in the top position when change to landscape in size class wA hR? I don't want to set the fixed constraint, I hope the red view stay top(landscape mode) if it's top in portrait mode and it stay bottom(landscape mode) if it's bottom in portrait mode. Hope I describe the issue clearly

Comment: You can't use auto layout and set frames. When you animate that view to the top (or the other one down) you need to change their constraints. If you change the frames (like you do now) the next time the auto layout engine does its job, it will remove the red view back to the location it has according to its constraints (set frame positions are just ignored).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just submitted a pull request on your github repo that has my solution for this problem. Here is a run down of what I did:

1) I removed the two views from the storyboard and added them programmatically in the `viewController`.

2) Now the constraints are added programmatically to the two views in the `viewController`

3) When the `Change` button is tapped, the constraints are removed and then added back opposite of how they previously were (i.e. view1 constants become view2 constraints and view2 constraints become view1 constraints).

Here is some of the relevant code:

```
@IBAction func change(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Remove existing constraints
    self.firstView.removeConstraints(self.firstView.constraints)
    self.secondView.removeConstraints(self.secondView.constraints)
    self.firstView.removeFromSuperview()
    self.secondView.removeFromSuperview()

    // Decide which view will recieve which constraints now based on their current sizes
    if firstView.frame.height == 50 {
        self.createAutoLayoutForViews(self.secondView, view2: self.firstView)
    } else {
        self.createAutoLayoutForViews(self.firstView, view2: self.secondView)
    }
}
```

To see the full implementation, please see my pull request or fork on the github repo [here](https://github.com/SomnusLee1988/SamplePorject)

*Note: I just made the views random sizes. If you want them to be sized differently, you will need to alter the auto layout constraints for the two views*